# admin-on-rest runtime configuration support

Tags: reactjs, docker, yarnpkg, admin-on-rest

I built a docker image (based on official nginx image) to serve the build folder, result of yarn build. My problem is that I have a unique image to be used both on test and prod environments. I don't want to have different images for each environment, instead i'd like to leverage on containers startup configuration in order to run my container with test or prod configuration. That is, some kind of configuration decoupled from the build task which can be applied on top of a build

The reason is that there are no differences between the 2 environments, except for my backend endpoint which is used by my custom http client inside admin-on-rest app.

Is there a support for this kind of configuration or should I implement something like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855#issuecomment-274803729) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like this by adding a new script to your image that updates the address used by nginx:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -z "$PROD" && "PROD" != '0' ]] ; then
    sed -i 's/address_in_file/test_env_address/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
else
    sed -i 's/address_in_file/prod_env_address/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
fi

nginx -g daemon off
```

It's not a nice solution but it works.

address_in_file is the current backend address defined in your configuration file

test_env_address is the new address that the should appear if the script is started with the environment variable PROD = 0 (or no PROD at all)

prod_env_address is the production address

Comment: Yep this could definitely work even though a bit nasty. I prefer this approach over the one depicted [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855#issuecomment-274803729). Wondering if there are other options... if not, i'll go with the one you suggested. thanks!

Comment: ps: not used by nginx but browser (that is, contained in js files)

Comment: If you find a different approach, please let me know since I'm using something similar and I'm not very proud of it